# Double-Hop Errors when running Skype for Business Cmdlets

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, skype-for-business

I am attempting to automate the Skype for Business Server installation process in Powershell, I have a script that remotes into specified machines and begins preparing them as Front-End servers. The problem lies when certain SfB cmdlets (SfB commands are all of the form "verb-Cs...", ex. Get-CsUser or Get-CsPool) are run in remote sessions, they throw the double-hop error:

```
Exception: Active Directory error "-2147016672" occurred while searching for domain controllers in domain...
```

This is after running Enable-CsComputer, which enables the computer's role-based off its definition in the topology (topology was published successfully). The user object is in all required groups (RTCUniversalServerAdmins, Schema Admins, CsAdministrators & Local Admin rights on all SfB Servers). Oddly enough, the command 'Import-CsConfiguration -localstore" does not throw errors, and it's in the same remote session. There may be other local or domain groups that I need to be in, but I cannot pinpoint exactly which and have not seen them documented in the Skype build guides. Skype commands that have parameters to specify targets or just pull data, such as Get-CsPool or Get-CsAdForest, do not have errors because they are run in the local scope. The Enable-CsComputer has no parameter for the computer name, it has to be executed from that machine itself.

Enabling CredSSP delegation on each server is not an option, and I'm not understanding why there is a "second hop" in this command! If the second hop was a resource on a file server or database, that would make sense, and be easy to solve, but in this case, I can't track it. Can anyone tell me what I may be missing?

Here's a code sample to try and illustrate. From the jumbox I get the pool data to create an array, and a session is opened to each machine:

```
$ServerArray =get-cspool -identity $poolName
$i=0
$SessionArray = @{}
foreach($server in $ServerArray.Computers){$SessionArray[$i] = new-PsSession -ComputerName $server}
foreach($session in $SessionArray.values){
invoke-Command -session $session -scriptBlock {
   #remote commands:
   import-csConfiguration -<config file path> -localstore; #no errors
   enable-CsReplica; #no errors
   enable-cscomputer; #double hop error here
}}
```

If I log into that machine and run the same command, it executes fine but the intention of the project is to automate it on an arbitrary number of machines.

Comment: I've had my fair share of double hop issues. My advice is to reconsider the tooling. Consider following the path of any tool that places an agent in the machine that executes locally.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's just trying to authenticate to a domain controller, which is reasonable. You'll have to approach this like any other double-hop issue.

Microsoft has an article dedicated to the double hop issue, and has a few solutions other than CredSSP that you can look at: [Making the second hop in PowerShell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the 'Resource-based Kerberos constrained delegation' with "ServerC" as the Domain Controller and that wasn't successful, but I definitely won't rule that out, perhaps with different syntax. the '$using:cred' method works in other cases, but is not practical for the 'Enable-CsComputer' command. The answer is probably there just not found yet. I agree, trying to authenticate with the DC makes sense but it's not clear why some commands would attempt to and others do not.